# echoing a value from a BASH function after a command has been run in the background

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to run the following, as a test for something else:

```
function echo_test {
  sleep 60 & > /dev/null
  returnpid=$!
  echo $returnpid
}

pidthatwasreturned=$(echo_test)

echo "This was the value that was returned by the function:"
echo $pidthatwasreturned
```

The problem is that the function doesn't exit and return until the sleep has finished, even though it has been run in the background. In the script that I am developing, the sleep command will effectively be replaced by a long running command. Is there some way in which I can rewrite this function to get it to return immediately?

Comment: Try `sleep 60 >/dev/null &`.

Answer (score 1):

The function exits, but the shell set's up a `pipe` from the function to the code that reads from `stdout` of the function and then places the result into the variable`pidthatwasreturned`.

This `stdout` file descriptor however is held open by the `sleep` command for 60 seconds.

Your function redirects the output for the echo command but not for the `sleep` command and for this reason, the variable assignment waits until `stdout` from the `sleep`is closed.

If you exchange `&` and `> /dev/null`, it works in the `Bourne Shell` and should work in `bash` as well unless there is a bug in `bash`.

Comment: Thanks Schily. This had me scratching my head for a while :-)

Comment: @Codemunger If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.